# An error occurred: null

Tags: jmeter

When i am starting jmeter than it showing the follwing error
An error occurred: null

My process to start jmeter is

root@L411:/opt/apache-jmeter-2.12/bin# sh jmeter
An error occurred: null

Answer (score 7):

This happened to me as well. In my case, I was running Jmeter 2.13 on OpenJDK 1.8 on my 64-bit Linux machine. I fixed it by installing Oracle's Java instead, and switching to it with:

```
alternatives --config java
```

I'm a bit annoyed that I have to do this now, as it used to work before (I think).

Answer (score 6):

What OS are you using? I was getting the same error in Fedora 27 and I fixed it by installing the OpenJDK runtime environment (java-1.8.0-openjdk)

```
sudo dnf install java-1.8.0-openjdk
```

Answer (score 5):

If after executing jmeter.sh your apache-jmeter-x.xx/bin/jmeter.log contains something like

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.HeadlessException
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:173)
```

you probably have `default-jdk-headless` installed.
Installing default package (`sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk`) fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error on macOS High Sierra while running jMeter.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.awt.Window.init
```

For me the problem was JVM not being able to identify a compatible graphics mode from the OS. To solve the problem I had to reset PRAM and NVRAM.

I followed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53216725/3798217) and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53216726/3798217).

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you check the jmeter.log file to understand the cause for the `null` exception.

If your log shows the stack trace

```
java.awt.HeadlessException: null
    at java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.checkHeadless(GraphicsEnvironment.java:208)
```

This could be because of 2 reasons:

1. Your shell's config file/dotfile (`.bashrc`, `.bashprofile`,`.zshrc`, etc.) is setting an env variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` and has the argument `-Djava.awt.headless=true`. (I had to set this to prevent the surefire plugin from stealing focus every time tests are executed)
2. Or you have a headless JDK installed which does not support GUI apps. Install a full JDK and add it to `PATH`