# Mac OS and java.lang.NullPointerException at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:497)

Tags: java, macos

I've been setting up a 2018 MacBook Pro for Java development. It's running Mojave 10.14.1 - just like the older machine I'm migrating from, an early 2013 MacBook Pro. I installed Java 1.8.0_192 and immediately noticed that I could not launch jars or any Java app that had a UI on this mac. I uninstalled and tried each of these: 1.8.0_172, 1.8.0_191, 1.8.0_192, and 11.0.1. I traced the issue further and found a common error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:497)
  at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537)
  at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420)
  at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385)
  at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1763)
  at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1838)
  at javax.swing.JWindow.<init>(JWindow.java:187)
  at javax.swing.JWindow.<init>(JWindow.java:139)
```

Curious, I launched our Swing-based product and it reported the same error. I googled and found only unanswered posts.

(revising this to be formatted as a question and not a blog post)

What gives?

Comment: You need to revise your question/answer so that it's not a blog post.  Rather, you should ask a "question" and then, in the answer section, provide the answer

Comment: True...I've revised formatting to be a question/answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution to this problem was simple, but not immediately obvious.

I dug into the JVM and found that the native code wasn't able to identify a compatible graphics mode from the OS. This results in a null GraphicsConfiguration. That's not good - it causes a NullPointerException in Window.java...guess what line. (Line 497)

I suspected the OS wasn't returning the right information about its graphics setup and then started to suspect the graphics driver. That's when I remembered Macs have parameter RAM (PRAM) and non-volatile RAM (NVRAM).

I zapped the PRAM and NVRAM and now the machine is working fine!

To zap the PRAM and NVRAM:

1. shut down your mac
2. restart while holding option+command+P+R
3. keep holding these until the mac appears to reboot again (the apple logo
   will appear, disappear, and reappear)

If your mac starts up without the disappearing mac logo, shut it down and retry.

[Reset NVRAM or PRAM on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063)

I hope resetting the PRAM helps others!

Comment: That's crazy if it works. I have users with this problem and can give them these instructions, but it's not ideal.

Comment: Ultimately I took this machine back to the Apple Store where they determined it had a bad video card. The replacement machine suffered none of these crazy afflictions, so it seems they were correct.

Comment: For those of you with the DisplayLink Driver as mentioned from @Praj answer, Ive also attempted this solution, it did not work for me.

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue and I found it reported [here](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63369).

In my case, I was using a docking station for my MacBook Pro and DisplayLink Driver for extended display. This made Jmeter crash.

The workaround was to disconnect my laptop from its docking station and launching the application.

Comment: Great! same issue with DisplayLink

Comment: I took a look at your report and recommend you report this to Apple. I traced this in depth through the JVM and found that the OS isn't returning a compatible graphics mode. If the OS doesn't return a graphics mode to the JVM, then no JVM will ever work when you get into this scenario.

Comment: Same issue!  Yet [another problem](https://displaylink.org/forum/archive/index.php/t-65351.html) with DisplayLink docks!

Comment: Supposedly there is a [fix in newer versions of Java](https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=66114).  However, I was unable to get it working with `openjdk 13.0.1 2019-10-15`.

Comment: For me, I was able to get the app I'm interested in to launch by opening my laptop so its display was active and then launch the app.  I didn't have to disconnect.  And once the app launched, I was able to close the laptop again and use the app on the monitor

Comment: @KCBaltz,@TrinitronX - I have a Dell 6000 docking station with DisplayPort and use this same workaround to start SQLDeveloper (also a JAva app)

Answer (score 1):

We have the same issue when trying to open an inhouse Java-based application in conjunction with Dell D6000 docks using DisplayLink software.

As others have suggested disconnecting the Dock then launching the application works after which you can reconnect the dock and move the application to the other screen.

The other way we have managed to get it to work is with the laptop open making the laptop screen the main display this is done in the system prefs in the display settings and moving the white bar to the laptop screen then opening the application.

I think it has been said before when the main display is one run through DisplayLink it can't detect the display so return a null value, even running most recent drivers (24th Aug 2020) this is still the case.

So its workarounds not solutions if you are in the same boat