# Jmeter NullPointerException when running the GUI

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

I have installed Jmeter using

> brew install Jmeter

when I run

> jmeter

from command line i get this error:

```
mac@macbook ~ $ jmeter
================================================================================ 
Don't use GUI mode for load testing !, only for Test creation and Test
debugging. For load testing, use CLI Mode (was NON GUI):    
 jmeter -n -t [jmx file] -l [results file] -e -o [Path to web report folder] & increase Java Heap to meet your test requirements:    Modify current
env variable HEAP="-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m" in the
jmeter batch file Check :
https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html
================================================================================ 
An error occurred: null
```

I checked the jmeter.log file and this is what I get:

```
2019-12-03 09:48:06,190 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: An error occurred: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null  at
java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_231]  at
java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537) ~[?:1.8.0_231]    at
java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420) ~[?:1.8.0_231]  at
java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385) ~[?:1.8.0_231]  at
javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1763)
~[?:1.8.0_231]    at
javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1838)
~[?:1.8.0_231]    at javax.swing.JWindow.<init>(JWindow.java:187)
~[?:1.8.0_231]    at javax.swing.JWindow.<init>(JWindow.java:139)
~[?:1.8.0_231]    at
org.apache.jmeter.SplashScreen.<init>(SplashScreen.java:45)
~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]    at
org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startGui(JMeter.java:376)
~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]    at
org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:545)
[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]     at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
~[?:1.8.0_231]    at
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
~[?:1.8.0_231]    at
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
~[?:1.8.0_231]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
~[?:1.8.0_231]    at
org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:253)
[ApacheJMeter.jar:5.2.1]
```

Java version:

```
java version "1.8.0_231" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
1.8.0_231-b11) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.231-b11, mixed mode)
```

anyone was able to fix this?

Comment: can you share full jmeter.log ? what is your os ?

Comment: Similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53216725/mac-os-and-java-lang-nullpointerexception-at-java-awt-window-initwindow-java49

Comment: Related discussion: https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=66114

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can it be the case you're using [DisplayLink](https://www.displaylink.com/)? If so, most probably you're suffering from [Java Apps crash on launch if connected to external DisplayLink device](https://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=66114) issue.

According to the [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure/) article:

> **Use Up-to-Date Software**
>
> Your test might fail if your software is out of date. Make sure you’re using the most recent versions of the following:
>
> **Java**  - use the latest 64-bit version of Java SE JDK or Server JRE where possible

So if you have to stay at Java 8 - consider upgrading to [Java SE Development Kit 8u231](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) (or whatever is the latest stable patch level), otherwise obtain the latest version of [Java Runtime Environment or SDK](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

If you cannot amend Java version - consider removing this DisplayLink device.

Comment: Are you a wizard :) I'm actually using DisaplyLink on my Mac which I had to install last week to use the work monitors and suddenly the JMeter stopped working. I just uninstalled it and everything worked. Thanks a lot for solving this for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as the OP on

```
mac os mojave 10.14.6, 
openjdk version "1.8.0_232"(Corretto-8.232.09.1 build 1.8.0_232-b09) and
jmeter 5.3.
```

I had external monitors connected to my mac laptop. Disconnected both displays. Opened the flap. Reconnected both displays. Now, jmeter GUI starts up fine.