# How to start Jmeter on mac? Running into "An error occurred: null"

Tags: jmeter

Looking at the jmeter.log file in the bin folder, I see the following exception being thrown:

```
2020-02-28 10:49:33,568 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: An error occurred: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.awt.Window.init(Window.java:497) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Window.java:537) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:420) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:385) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities$SharedOwnerFrame.<init>(SwingUtilities.java:1763) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at javax.swing.SwingUtilities.getSharedOwnerFrame(SwingUtilities.java:1838) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at javax.swing.JWindow.<init>(JWindow.java:187) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at javax.swing.JWindow.<init>(JWindow.java:139) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.jmeter.SplashScreen.<init>(SplashScreen.java:45) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.startGui(JMeter.java:356) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:524) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_191]
    at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:245) [ApacheJMeter.jar:4.0 r1823414]
```

I've tried two different versions of jmeter (4.0 and 5.2.1)and both versions throw the same exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jmeter NullPointerException when running the GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59164207/jmeter-nullpointerexception-when-running-the-gui)

Comment: Yes, thank you @SoheilPourbafrani , it was the Displaylink dock I was using. I just disconnect it now, start jmeter and then plug the dock back in.